# Examples of non-self-induced algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, algebras

Let $A$ be a (possibly non-unital) algebra over $\mathbb C$.  We say that $A$ is *self-induced* if the product map $m:A \otimes_A A \rightarrow A$ is an isomorphism.  Here $A \otimes_A A$ is the balanced tensor product, the quotient of $A\otimes A$ by the linear span of elements of the form $ab\otimes c - a\otimes bc$.

This notion seems to have been introduced by Gronbaek in [Morita equivalence for self-induced Banach algebras](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0864.46026) and was further studied by Meyer in [Smooth and rough modules over self-induced algebras](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1252.18019).  If $A$ is unital, or more generally, has local, one-sided, units, then $A$ is self-induced.  I am interested in *non-trivial* examples of $A$ which are not self-induced.

> What is an example of $A$ which is not self-induced, but such that the product map is surjective, and such that the product is [non-degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_bilinear_form) (so for each non-zero $a\in A$ there are $b,c\in A$ with $ba\not=0, ac\not=0$).

---

I have tagged this functional analysis, as the notion seems to have arisen in the context of topological algebras (and so people working in this area might know examples).  But the question does not ask about the topological case.  I would be interested to know if this idea is studied in non-topological contexts under a different name?

Comment: Now also asked on Mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419736/examples-of-non-self-induced-algebras

Comment: Sorry to bring this up after half a year (and not even answering your question) but is there even a natural example of a ring without local units but is self-induced? I can cook up several rings of smooth functions without idempotent (hence have no local units) but I am having difficulties to check they are self-induced or not which is a purely algebraic condition

Comment: Just to clarify the last phrase in my earlier comment. I think the purely  algebraic condition made it hard for me to check the injectivity of the product map. Its surjectivity otoh (aka whether the rings I cooked up are idempotent or not) may be resolved by some analytical techniques